# wifi interface somtimes doesn't work in archlinux

Tags: wifi, driver, archlinux

Sometimes I boot into Archlinux networkmanager doesn't use the wifi adapter while it shows its being used.

**linux-firmware is installed**

`lspci -k`

*04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)*

*Subsystem: Dell Device 1810*

*Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci*

*Kernel modules: ath10k_pci*

`ip link`

*1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000*

*2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether
2c:ee:7f:2c:ee:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this before where the wifi adapter is not shown in ip link too. My solution to that was to install `linux-firmware` during boot installation rather than after as `udev` somehow did not auto detect the wifi adapter after boot installation.

Not sure if this is unique to my computer but hope it helps!

Comment: I already installed it during the USB installation but it was not the problem, the good thing is it actually became very rare now, but thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe you should provide more details on how you did your installation or if it was working before what was the most recent thing you did before the wifi adapter cracks. I remember debugging a lot as there are many factors that can potentially affect this. Think others would need more context to help give you inspiration on where to debug.